# Eliminar todos losespacios en blanco al principio y final de una palabra expresion regular

Tags: java, regex

Necesito de su ayuda debido a que tengo una expresión regular para todos los espacios en blanco al principio y final  de una palabra, pero he intentado de varias maneras y no logro obtener el resultado esperado, me pueden orientar por favor.

**Palabra 1:**
    `4. numero de identificación`

**Palabra 2:**
`3. nombre`

**Expresión Regular**

```
String texto = texto.replaceAll("^\\s{2,}|$\\s|\\s+(?=\\s)", "")
```

---

Pruebas realizadas:

**Prueba No. 1a**

```
String textoA = "3. nombre    ";

String resultadoA = textoA.trim(); **resultado:** `3. nombre
```

**Prueba No. 1b**

```
String textoA = "3. nombre    ";
```

`String resultadoA  = textoA .replaceAll("^\\s{2,}|$\\s|\\s+(?=\\s)", "");`

**resultado esperado:**

**Palabra 1:**
`4. numero de identificación`

**Palabra 2:**
`3. nombre`

Comment: Puedes hacerle un trim() al texto

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez ya tambien lo intente y no elimina los espacios, por eso recurrí a un regex

Comment: Creo que tendrás que poner algunos ejemplos de entrada y de resultado esperado ya que tal cual está escrito induce a confusión. Por ejemplo, para la entrada `una   palabra`, si quitamos todos los espacios que rodean las palabras quedaría todo junto: `unapalabra`. Tendrías que definir en qué casos se quitan los espacios y en qué casos no, y a poder ser con ejemplos.

Comment: También estaría bien que escribieses lo que has intentado. A veces indicar el fallo en tu código es más constructivo que presentar una solución alternativa

Comment: @Julio adjunto ejemplos realizados, lo que he podido ver es que no son espacios particulares, porque son como caracteres especiales, porque cuando los volvi a copia no me permitia generar los espacios.

Comment: Gracias, quizás sean tabuladores, pero deberían encontrase con \s en cualquier caso. Cual es el resultado que esperas para los ejemplos de "Palabra no1 A" y "Paralabra no1 B"? Cómo deberían quedar?

Comment: @Julio mil gracias Julio por tu colaboración, mira ya tambien buequ por regex si era un `tab` y tampoco lo identifica, acabo de editar la pregunta indicandote el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente expresión regular para eliminar 'blancos' (espacios, tabuladores, ...) al inicio y al final de un string:

```
mensaje.replaceAll("^\\p{Zs}+|\\p{Zs}+$", "");
```

Parece que trim no funciona porque el texto en cuestión debe estar utilizando alguno de los otros [espacios alternativos de unicode](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html)

Con respecto a la expresión regular, la diferencia respecto a `\s` es que `\s` solo trataría los espacios ASCII, mientras que `\p{Zs}` también tiene en cuenta los espacios unicode.

Otra opción podría ser utilizar [StringUtils.strip](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#strip%28java.lang.String%29), como comentan en esta [entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652770/how-to-remove-unicode-spaces-from-string-returned-by-reader-readline) en StackOverflow. Parece que funcionaría con los diferentes espacios unicode.

Comment: hola, mil gracias por el aporte y ayuda, dejo el enlace con un ejemplo del inconveniente presentado: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/SUs

Comment: Parece que es porque son espacios unicode. He cambiado mi respuesta, mira a ver si te funciona así.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, acabo de aprender mas cosas de las que que pregunte, no tenia ni idea de los espacios unicode, mil y mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente no estas llamando correctamente la funcion trim, prueba de esta forma:

```
public class Task {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String source = "    4. numero de identificación    ";
        String result = source.trim();

        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

Documentacion: [funcion trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Comment: seria bueno mencionar que esto se debe a que los String en Java son Immutables [Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

Comment: Ya lo habia intentando y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, motivo por el cual me pase a una expresion regular he podido ver es que no son espacios particulares, son como caracteres especiales.